# How to disable direct linking with htaccess after subdomain redirection?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain which redirects to a specific directory address. How can I disable that directory address if it is accessed directly?

i.e. `sub.domain.com` redirects to `domain.com/sub`. When I access `domain.com/sub` directly it should redirect to error 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I access domain.com/sub directly it should redirect to error 404.

You can use this rule as first rule in `sub/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 1):

In htaccess in your document root, add this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^folder - [R=404,L]
```

This will redirect all requests that start with **/folder** to 404  page if requested host is not  **sub.domain.com** .